# No holomorphic injective function such that $f(B(0,1))=\mathbb{C}$!

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I show that there is no holomorphic injective function $f:B(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(B(0,1))=\mathbb{C}$, where $B(0,1)$ is the unit open ball centered in the origin?

I know that the derivative of such function is non-zero at every point and tried to reach a contradiction, but I couldn't get it. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 8):

Hint: Injective holomorphic functions are biholomorphisms and L_*_*'s Theorem.

Comment: By that you mean Liouville?

Comment: @GustavoMarra By that I mean "you fill it on OP, since hopefully you want to have to think a little" :)

Comment: Well, that was unnecessary.

Comment: @GustavoMarra What do you mean?

Comment: I thought that was rude until I saw your smiling face. I'm sorry :)

Comment: @GustavoMarra :)